# What is this language exactly?

Tags: asp.net, web, frontpage

I have a family friend that asked me to help them out with their website. They are hosted on godaddy.com and I told them to just give me the ftp information and I would fix up their site. However, when I opened the index.htm file this is what it looked like:

```
vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl
vti_author:SR|BUDDY\\Owner
vti_modifiedby:SR|BUDDY\\Owner
vti_timelastmodified:TR|13 Jul 2010 07:07:58 -0000
vti_timecreated:TR|12 Jul 2010 17:46:18 -0000
vti_title:SR|Specializing in 4
vti_extenderversion:SR|5.0.2.2623
vti_lineageid:SR|{1D9C5476-C710-4188-962B-5CCC568CF1ED}
vti_backlinkinfo:VX|frequently_asked_questions.htm contact_information.htm about_us.htm Products.htm
vti_nexttolasttimemodified:TW|13 Jul 2010 05:58:33 -0000
vti_cacheddtm:TX|13 Jul 2010 07:07:58 -0000
vti_filesize:IR|1177
vti_cachedtitle:SR|Specializing in 4
vti_cachedbodystyle:SR|<body text="#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#000000">
vti_cachedlinkinfo:VX|S|MMADweblogo.JPG S|Geoff's\\ pictures\\ 122.jpg H|Products.htm
vti_cachedsvcrellinks:VX|FSUS|MMADweblogo.JPG FSUS|Geoff's\\ pictures\\ 122.jpg FHUS|Products.htm
vti_cachedneedsrewrite:BR|false
vti_cachedhasbots:BR|false
vti_cachedhastheme:BR|false
vti_cachedhasborder:BR|false
vti_metatags:VR|HTTP-EQUIV=Content-Language en-us GENERATOR Microsoft\\ FrontPage\\ 5.0 ProgId FrontPage.Editor.Document HTTP-EQUIV=Content-Type text/html;\\ charset=windows-1252
vti_charset:SR|windows-1252
vti_language:SR|en-us
vti_progid:SR|FrontPage.Editor.Document
vti_generator:SR|Microsoft FrontPage 5.0
```

I see stuff about Microsoft FrontPage, but have never seen this before.

Comment: Take a look at this..http://wordpress.org/support/topic/vt1-encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are Meta-key. Refer to this [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd624746%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

MS Sharepoint !

You can get more information - [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc339475%28v=office.12%29.aspx)